# Can I force global styles to be loaded after styles imported from antd inside node_modules?

Tags: sass, gatsby, antd

I built a small test project to try out the [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/overview/) components. I am using `gatsby-plugin-antd` and `antd`, as well as `gatsby-plugin-sass`. My problem is that the Antd theme overwrites my global styles. I have tried putting the import for the global styles in `gatsby-browser.js` and in my Layout component but the styles loaded from inside node_modules always end up after my own global styles.

To be fair, I am not sure if the issue lies with Gatsby, the SASS plugin, the Antd plugin or even babel-import or webpack.

```
// When loaded in gatsby-browser.js
import "./src/css/public-sans.scss"
import "./src/css/styles.scss"

// When loaded in Layout component
import "../css/public-sans.scss"
import "../css/styles.scss"
```

Is there a way to ensure that my styles override the ones set in the Antd stylesheets, both in develop and build mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [customizing the `html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) output. You can get it by:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

Or manually, copying from `.cache/default-html.js` and pasting it in `/src`.

Once done, it should look something like:

```
  <head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    {props.headComponents}
    {/* custom here your styles order */}
  </head>
```

*Source: extending [Kyle Mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182702/kyle-mathews)'s answer in [this GitHub thread](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182702/kyle-mathews) (which you may find insightful).*

You can change your HTML output by manipulating those lines. If Gatsby finds an `html.js` inside `/src` folder, it will take it to create the final output.